# Allow html/script embed code in angular templates

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 9 app and I need to run following embed code to show the reviews on site

```
<div data-token="" class="romw-reviews"></div>
<script src="https://reviewsonmywebsite.com/js/embedLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have used `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml` for this but its only showing the html but script is not loading hence the reviews are not showing. If I use `SecurityContext.SCRIPT` then it returns `unsafe value used in a script context`  error. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: put script in index.html

Comment: you have to put script inside index.html

Comment: I tried it but then script loads first and html after it hence the content is not loading.

Comment: Add the script dynamically once your app is loaded, or if you know the content of the script you can try to call one of its function to instruct the script to redo its processing (it depends on how the script is written)